# Autocorrelation in binary time series with multiple groups

Tags: r, time-series, binary-data, cross-correlation

I am trying to assess the degree of autocorrelation in a time series of binary hierarchically-structured ecological data. I have data on the presence or absence (1 or 0) of an organism measured at multiple independent sites (n = 469) every 6 months over 11 years (yielding 22 equally-spaced time points).

Here is some dummy data to work with:

```
# Create dummy time series (random 0 or 1 value for absent or present)
# Format of time series is matrix with rows as sites and columns as time points

set.seed(1)

dat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 469*22, replace=T), nrow=469, ncol=22)
```

I would like to know the degree of serial correlation in organism presence/absence at each site (time = t vs. time = t - 1, t - 2, t - 3, ... , t - 21). While the data are spatially structured, I don't really care about site-specific trends, only the overall relationship. Can someone help me determine the appropriate way to format the data for use in a package (e.g., "acf") or custom function designed to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
set.seed(1)

dat <- data.frame(id=1:469,matrix(sample(0:1, 469*22, replace=T), nrow=469, ncol=22))
library(tidyr);library(dplyr)


dat %>%
  gather(time,dummy,-id)->dat2
library(lme4)
model<-glmer(dummy~time+(1|id),dat2,family="binomial")
vcov(model) #variance-covariance matrix
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like this direction but I'm not sure if it is giving me the right response. From GLMM analysis (using glmer) I know that presence-absence at time t-1 is a great predictor of presence-absence at time t. But this doesn't come through in a plot of the variance-covariance matrix for the model you suggested. See level plot here (shows my real data, not the dummy data): http://s10.postimg.org/pj468ak21/vocv_levelplot.jpg